# TryCatch loop in RCurl, XML and readHTMLTable

Tags: xml, r, try-catch, rcurl

I am trying to obtain all of England's international football results and put it into a dataframe in R. The excellent website www.11v11.com has all the results I need, however I've run into a problem in the years where there are no recorded results- and hence no html tables. Here is my code:

```
resultloop<-function(team,startyear,endyear){

library(RCurl)
library(XML)

x<-vector(mode = "list", length = endyear)

for(k in seq(endyear,startyear))

{
  theurl<-paste("http://www.11v11.com/teams/",team,"/tab/matches/season/",k,sep="")
  tables<-readHTMLTable(theurl)
  n.rows <- unlist(lapply(tables, function(t) dim(t)[1]))
  newtable<-tables[[which.max(n.rows)]]

  x[[k]]<-newtable  
  x=x[-(which(sapply(x,is.null),arr.ind=TRUE))]

  y<-do.call("rbind",x)

 }

return(y)


}
```

If I ran

```
resultloop("england",1996,2013)
```

for instance, the dataframe appears nice and dandy- however if I ran

```
resultloop("england",1944,1945)
```

I get the error

```
Error in tables[[which.max(n.rows)]] : 
attempt to select less than one element
```

What I want to do is use an iferror function to skip a particular year if there isn't a table, and continue with the loop. I've had a look at tryCatch but am struggling to understand it- can somebody help me out please?

Comment: [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20321073/1036500) an example of what you're looking for - a loop with `readHTMLTable` that uses error handling to skip empty results.