# R Webscrape Function - Indexing Vector Only Returns 1 Result

Tags: r, web-scraping

I have a function that I am calling from a loop.  The basic idea is to load in a list of URLs and build a data frame where each row is a URL and each column is an attribute I am interested in scraping.  When I ran it initially I didn't include the index (square brackets at the ends) and it worked fine until I hit a URL that had multiple elements on the page.  So, I changed it to the code below and don't get an error, but I only get one row in my data frame no matter how many URLs I give it.

```
    require(RCurl)
    require(XML)

    scrp.getDtls <- function(url){
      src = getURL(url,encoding="UTF-8")
      prsd = htmlParse(src)
      title = xpathSApply(prsd, "//meta[@name='title']/@content")[1] #added to return first element only
      brand = xpathSApply(prsd, "//meta[@itemprop='brand']/@content")[1]
      model = xpathSApply(prsd, "//meta[@itemprop='model']/@content")[1]
      upc = xpathSApply(prsd, "//meta[@itemprop='productID']/@content")[1]
      price = xpathSApply(prsd, "//div/meta[@itemprop='price']/@content")[1]
      x = data.frame(title,brand,model,upc,price)
    }

    urls = read.csv("urls.csv", header=FALSE)

    x = NA
    for(url in urls){
      x = rbind(x,scrp.getDtls(url))
    }

    x = x[-1,]
    View(x)

    #CSV file partial contents
    "http://www.walmart.com/ip/Suave-Naturals-Ocean-Breeze-Shampoo-22.5-oz/10293577"
    "http://www.walmart.com/ip/Gillette-Fusion-Cartridges-4-count/14071267"
    "http://www.walmart.com/ip/Sensodyne-Pronamel-Mint-Essence-Toothpaste-4-oz/10316819"
    "http://www.walmart.com/ip/Speed-Stick-Ocean-Surf-Deodorant-3-oz/11965072"
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Your `for` loop isn't quite right. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20321073/1036500) for an example of something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
require(RCurl)
require(XML)
```

Function definition

```
scrp_getdtls <- function(url){
  src = getURL(url,encoding="UTF-8")
  prsd = htmlParse(src)
  title = xpathSApply(prsd, "//meta[@name='title']/@content")[1] #added to return first element only
  brand = xpathSApply(prsd, "//meta[@itemprop='brand']/@content")[1]
  model = xpathSApply(prsd, "//meta[@itemprop='model']/@content")[1]
  upc = xpathSApply(prsd, "//meta[@itemprop='productID']/@content")[1]
  price = xpathSApply(prsd, "//div/meta[@itemprop='price']/@content")[1]
  data.frame(title,brand,model,upc,price)
}
```

urls

```
urls <- c("http://www.walmart.com/ip/Suave-Naturals-Ocean-Breeze-Shampoo-22.5-oz/10293577",
"http://www.walmart.com/ip/Gillette-Fusion-Cartridges-4-count/14071267",
"http://www.walmart.com/ip/Sensodyne-Pronamel-Mint-Essence-Toothpaste-4-oz/10316819",
"http://www.walmart.com/ip/Speed-Stick-Ocean-Surf-Deodorant-3-oz/11965072")
```

Use `lapply` to pass each url to the function, and use `rbind` with
`do.call` to combine rows.

```
out <- lapply(urls, scrp_getdtls)
do.call(rbind, out)

##                                                     title       brand
## content      Suave Naturals Ocean Breeze Shampoo, 22.5 oz       Suave
## content1              Gillette Fusion Cartridges, 4 count    Gillette
## content2 Sensodyne Pronamel Mint Essence Toothpaste, 4 oz   Sensodyne
## content3           Speed Stick Ocean Surf Deodorant, 3 oz Speed Stick
##             model          upc price
## content     89280 079400832801   1.5
## content1 SFS ONLY 047400156579 15.97
## content2    83050 310158830504  4.92
## content3    93008 022200930086  1.98
```