# How to scrape mutiple tables indexing both year+page?

Tags: r, xml

Thanks for post https://stackoverflow.com/a/7775721/7140722

But how to scrape multiple years?

This is the structure of the query:

```
http://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.php?Year=1994&lang=&page=1
http://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.php?Year=1994&lang=&page=2
```

I want to scrape more years. My code:

```
Year <- 1990:1994

url1 = 'http://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.php?Year='
url3 = '&lang=&page='

getPage <- function(page){
  require(XML)
  url = paste(url1, Year, url3, page, sep = "")
  tab = readHTMLTable(url, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)[[1]]
  return(tab)
}

pages    = llply(1:3,getPage, .progress = 'text') 
crash_all_Years = do.call('rbind', pages)
```

But it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to construct a list of urls first and then loop over that list with `lapply` (or `ldply` from the `plyr` package) to get the pages.

You can improve your code as follows:

```
# load the 'XML' package
library(XML)

# set the variables needed to construct the urls
years <- 1990:1994
url_1 <- 'http://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.php?Year='
url_3 <- '&lang=&page='
pages <- 1:2

# construct a list of pages to scrape
yp <- expand.grid(pages, years)
urls <- sprintf('%s%s%s%s', url_1, yp[[2]], url_3, yp[[1]])

# a simplified scrape function
getPage <- function(u){ readHTMLTable(u, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)[[1]] }

# loop over the list of urls and scrape each one
plst <- lapply(urls, getPage)

# bind the resulting list of dataframes into one dataframe
pages.df <- do.call(rbind, plst)
```

which will get you a dataframe with the airplane crashes of the first two pages for each year from 1990 to 1994:

```
> head(pages.df)
         date                             type registration                                operator fat.             location Â   pic cat
1 02-JAN-1990 CASA/Nurtanio NC-212 Aviocar 200       PK-PCM                      Pelita Air Service    9      Banten Bay, ...       Â  A1
2 03-JAN-1990          BN-2A Trislander Mk.III       YJ-RV3                                  Vanair    0 near Port Vila-Ba...       Â  A1
3 04-JAN-1990    Swearingen SA227-AC Metro III       N31138 Chautauqua Airlines, opf. USAir Express    0       Hagerstown, MD       Â  O1
4 05-JAN-1990       Lockheed L-100-30 Hercules       D2-THB                      Angola Air Charter    0      Menongue Air...          C1
5 05-JAN-1990      Fokker F-28 Fellowship 4000       LV-MZD                   Aerolineas Argentinas    0      Villa Gesell...          A1
6 06-JAN-1990      Lockheed L-1329 JetStar 731        N96GS                                Grecoair    1      Miami Intern...       Â  A1
> tail(pages.df)
            date                          type registration                  operator fat.        location Â   pic cat
995  06-NOV-1994                    Antonov 26     RA-88286 KIT Space & Transport Air    0 Omulyovka River       Â  A1
996  09-NOV-1994                    Learjet 55       PT-LIG       LÃ­der TÃ¡xi AÃ©reo    0 Rio de Janei...          A1
997  12-NOV-1994 Beechcraft 200 Super King Air       D2-EOJ                   Endiama    0 Huambo-Alban...          A1
998  13-NOV-1994   Fokker F-27 Friendship 400M       7T-VRK              Air AlgÃ©rie    0 Palma de Mal...       Â  H2
999  16-NOV-1994       Beechcraft C99 Commuter       N63995               Ameriflight    1      Avenal, CA          A1
1000 18-NOV-1994                Tupolev 134A-3       HA-LBK                     Malev    0 Budapest-Fer...          O1
```

With `ldply` you can integrate the last two steps into one:

```
library(plyr)
pages.df <- ldply(urls, getPage)
```

NOTES:

- When you want all pages for each year, create a longer `pages` vector. For example with `pages <- 1:6`. The urls that don't exist will not be scraped and thus not included in the final dataframe. Using this, you will get a dataframe with 1238 rows, exactly the number of accidents in 1990 - 1994.
- In the `sprintf` code, each `%s` stands for a string that needs to be pasted together. See also `?sprintf`.